# touch command is not executing with ansible

Tags: ansible

In this ansible-playbook, the first task is not executing but the second task is executing fine
how can debug the issue

```
 - name: Transfer and execute a script.
#ansible-playbook -vvv createNode.yml --extra-vars "MASTER_URL=http://localhost:8080 MASTER_USERNAME=rajendar MASTER_PASSWORD=@Oracle38 NODE_NAME=testNode14 NUM_EXECUTORS=2"
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  vars:

  tasks:
      command: touch /Users/rajendartalatam/Desktop/anible.text
  tasks:
    - name: Copy and Execute the script 
      command: sh ./nodeCreate.sh  {{MASTER_URL}} {{MASTER_USERNAME}} {{MASTER_PASSWORD}} {{NODE_NAME}} {{NUM_EXECUTORS}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`tasks:`* is actually the [list of tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#tasks-list). The correct syntax is below

```
tasks:
  - command: touch /Users/rajendartalatam/Desktop/anible.text
  - name: Copy and Execute the script 
    command: sh ./nodeCreate.sh ...
```

Comment: after changing to this also no luck, but I have changed command to the shell then it is created but I am not sure of the reason